# C: getting data from a provided address

Tags: c

Let's say I've malloc something.

```
char *ptr = malloc(sizeof(char *));
ptr = "AB";
```

ptr is like 0x08123412

So now I'd like to do something like.

```
char *addr = "0x08123412";
```

How can I get back AB from addr.

Please assume that the address doesn't change in the meanwhile.

Comment: The `malloc` is wrong..... BTW, there isn't a need to `malloc` if you are going to do `ptr = "AB";` . To get `"AB"` from `addr`, just use `addr=ptr;`. You can't expect the address of `ptr` to be constant!

Comment: @CoolGuy: what exactly is wrong in `malloc(sizeof(char *)`?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Probably the obvious memory leak following that line?

Comment: @Lundin: but this is what happens after `malloc`. `malloc` itself is good. There is also no checking for errors. I agree it's not necessary here.

Comment: And why would you want to allocate a pointer, which points at another pointer, that is allocated on the heap? This code simply doesn't make any sense and therefore neither does the question. I think the OP might be confused because they think `char*` is some sort of string class?

Answer (score 2):

```
char *ptr = malloc(sizeof(char *));
ptr = "AB";
```

This is a memory leak, because you have lost the address returned by `malloc()` and won't be able to send that address to `free()`.

```
char *addr = "0x08123412";
```

Although I'm having trouble understanding what you are trying to accomplish here, this is valid. No call to `malloc()` was needed. Note that this code declares a `char` pointer, and points it to the string "0x08123412".

To get back a previously used address, you'll need to save it somewhere. That is why you cannot be overwriting your pointer values. You need to hang on to them if you might need them later.

Comment: OP is asking how to set `addr` to the fixed address `0x08123412`.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo: It's debatable as to if that's what he's asking. But, at any rate, that is not what he asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *ptr = malloc(sizeof(char *));
ptr = "AB";
char *addr = "0x08123412";
```

Now let's replace the last instruction with this:
`char *addr = 0x08123412;`

It is probably what you meant, it makes more sense.
So here we go:
First, you wrote `malloc(sizeof (char *))`, you probably intended to write `malloc(sizeof (char))` because according to this code, you are allocating a pointer to char, not a char, hopefully malloc returns a pointer to void, which will be implicitely cast into the `char *ptr` you have declared.

Next instruction: `ptr = "AB"`. What happens here is that the compiler will allocate "AB" as a string literal probably in the .rodata section. 'ptr' will hold the address at which "AB" was put.
Until now, here is your memory layout:

```
ptr lives at address X // &ptr = X  
"AB" lives at address Y // &("AB") = Y  
ptr contains Y // ptr = Y
```

Now the address returned by malloc, which you say is 0x08123412, let's call it Z, is the address of the memory location allocated by malloc(), which you lost when assigning "AB" to ptr. But supposing you kept it somewhere, you still cannot reach "AB" with it. The only way to reach the string "AB" is to know its address, and right now, the only thing that can help you with that is ptr, since it still holds that address. Overwrite it and "AB" is lost forever.